# Drawing Quads in OpenGL from .obj File

Tags: c++, opengl, blender

I'm parsing a .obj (created in Blender, if that helps) into a C++ program in OpenGL, and it seems to be coming close. It seems to correctly find the vertices that are needed here. I'm trying to create a capital block letter I that moves around. Here's my code for parsing:

```
bool loadObjectFile(const char * filepath, std::vector < glm::vec3 > & out_vertices, std::vector < glm::vec3 > & out_normals)
{
    std::vector< unsigned int > vertexIndices;
    std::vector< glm::vec3 > temp_vertices;
    std::vector< glm::vec3 > temp_normals;
    glm::vec3 tempFaceNormal;

    FILE * file = fopen(filepath, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Impossible to open the file !\n");
        return false;
    }

    while (1)
    {
        char lineHeader[128];
        // read the first word of the line
        int res = fscanf(file, "%s", lineHeader);
        if (res == EOF)
            break; // EOF = End Of File. Quit the loop.

        // else : parse lineHeader
        if (strcmp(lineHeader, "v") == 0)
        {
            glm::vec3 vertex;
            fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z);
            temp_vertices.push_back(vertex);
            glm::vec3 zeroface;
            zeroface.x = 0, zeroface.y = 0, zeroface.z = 0;
            temp_normals.push_back(zeroface);
        }
        else if (strcmp(lineHeader, "f") == 0)
        {
            unsigned int vertexIndex[3];
            int matches = fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2]);

            if (matches != 3)
            {
                printf("File can't be read by our simple parser : ( Try exporting with other options\n");
                return false;
            }

            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
            vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);

            tempFaceNormal = computeNormal(temp_vertices[vertexIndex[0] - 1], temp_vertices[vertexIndex[1] - 1], temp_vertices[vertexIndex[2] - 1]);

            temp_normals[vertexIndex[0] - 1] += tempFaceNormal;
            temp_normals[vertexIndex[1] - 1] += tempFaceNormal;
            temp_normals[vertexIndex[2] - 1] += tempFaceNormal;
        }
    }

    // For each vertex of each triangle
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i++)
    {
        unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
        glm::vec3 vertex = temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
        out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }

    //For each vertex normal
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp_normals.size(); i++)
    {
        out_normals.push_back(glm::normalize(temp_normals[i]));
    }
}

glm::vec3 computeNormal(glm::vec3 const & a, glm::vec3 const & b, glm::vec3 const & c)
{
    //Returns the (not normalized) face normal of each triangle
    return glm::cross(c - a, b - a);
}
```

Here's the code I'm using to draw the parsed vertices:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glColor3f(0.2, 0.2, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
{
    glVertex3f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
    glTexCoord3f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
}
for (int i = 0; i < normals.size(); i++)
{
    glNormal3f(normals[i].x, normals[i].y, normals[i].z);
}
glEnd();
```

This produces the following (screenshots):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qCowcn51DnQk1mT0hSUjZWc00/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qCowcn51DndTBJRFctV1lOQlk/view?usp=sharing

Here, the vertices seem to be correct, but the faces seem to be drawn incorrectly.

Comment: It looks like your parsing code assumes that the OBJ file contains triangles, but then you use `GL_QUADS` for drawing. There is **a lot** wrong in this code, not sure if this is specific enough for the StackOverflow format.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about other things that are wrong with this code? Drawing it using GL_QUADS and GL_QUAD_STRIP seemed to produce similarly ugly results.

Comment: glVertex3f, glBegin, glColor3f, glEnd, etc. are deprecated since openGL 3.1

Comment: Okay...so what would you recommend using instead of those functions? I'm something of an OpenGL noob.

Comment: In modern OpenGL, you would use what is called a VBO (vertex buffer object), and a VAO (vertex array object), to store your vertices, nomals etc, then draw the mesh using either glDrawArrays, or glDrawElements.

I would recommend having a look at the tutorials at http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/

They are a series of really good, modern OpenGL tutorials.
And in it's 7th tutorial, it goes through the creation of an obj model loader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of issues in this code. I won't go into a lot of detail on most of these, but wanted to at least point out the main issues.

### OBJ parsing

The main part of what you're doing is probably fine as long as you generate the OBJ files yourself, and control exactly what they contain. If you wanted to be able to parse more general OBJ files, you would need a lot more. For example:

- Other record types beyond "v" and "f". OBJ files can contain other data. Part of them, like normals ("vn") and texture coordinates ("vt") are often critical for OpenGL rendering. Beyond that, there are a lot more that may or may not be useful depending on what you want. But at least you have to be able to skip over records you're not parsing.
- Index values can be negative, making them relative to the current position.
- Faces can have any number of vertices.
- The format for faces has up to 3 indices (vertex/texcoord/normal) per vertex, separated by slashes.

### Primitive type mismatch

This is probably the biggest problem. Your parsing code reads 3 vertices per face, which means that it expects all faces to be triangles:

```
int matches = fscanf(file, "%d %d %d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2]);
if (matches != 3)
{
    printf("File can't be read by our simple parser : ( Try exporting with other options\n");
    return false;
}
```

But then the rendering code renders the faces as quads:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
```

If the file contains triangles, you need to use that as primitive type for rendering:

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
```

If it contains quads, you need to parse 4 vertex indices per face, and update the rest of the parsing code accordingly.

### Normal array

The code contains logic to rearrange the vertices based on the order of the vertex indices in the faces:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i++)
{
    unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
    glm::vec3 vertex = temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1];
    out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
}
```

But it just copies the normals in the original order of the vertices:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < temp_normals.size(); i++)
{
    out_normals.push_back(glm::normalize(temp_normals[i]));
}
```

Instead, it needs to rearrange the normals the same way as the vertices. This could be done as part of the vertex loop:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < vertexIndices.size(); i++)
{
    unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
    out_vertices.push_back(temp_vertices[vertexIndex - 1]);
    out_normals.push_back(glm::normalize(temp_normals[vertexIndex - 1]));
}
```

### Specification of normals during rendering

The rendering code contains a separate loop over the normals after looping over the vertices. Specifying the normals this way does absolutely noting. `glNormal3fv()` needs to be called before `glVertex3fv()` to specify the normal for that specific vertex.

Instead of having two separate loops, the rendering loop should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vertices.size(); i++)
{
    glNormal3f(normals[i].x, normals[i].y, normals[i].z);
    glVertex3f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
}
```

The `glTexCoord3f()` calls would also go *before* `glVertex3f()`, but you don't have texture coordinates in the first place.

### Obsolete OpenGL

The rendering calls you are using, `glBegin()`/`glEnd()`, `glVertex3f()`, etc., are legacy functionality. This is commonly called immediate mode, is deprecated, and not available anymore in modern version of OpenGL (OpenGL 3.x/4.x core profile, OpenGL ES 2.0/3.x).

For modern rendering, start by learning about Vertex Buffer Objects (VBO) and Vertex Array Objects (VAO) to specify your vertices. You can then use `glDrawElements()` or `glDrawArrays()` to draw entire objects with a single call.

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately figured out what I can do. Because I had exported the .obj file from Bender as a set of quads, I was using GL_QUADS and GL_QUADSTRIP. For some reason, those two produced kind of bizarre, ugly results. I just imported the .obj file back into Blender, and turned the mesh into triangles instead of quads. Then, I gave those files to this code and it all worked. Thanks everyone!